# Strange behavior with URL rewriting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite some url's. So I have page which is `userAction.php` and I rewrite it to `/login/` like this

```
RewriteRule ^login/$ /userAction.php [L]
```

now on that page login I have two forms - Login and Register. When user make registration and he finish with it the page is still userAction.php but with message: `userAction.php?action=joined`. I want to rewrite this to `login?action=joined`. Here is what I'm tried but it it redirecting me to 404 error

```
RewriteRule ^login?action=joined/$ /fun-second/userAction.php?action=joined [L]
```

So this is the whole `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^login/$ /userAction.php [L]
RewriteRule ^login/?action=joined/$ /userAction.php?action=joined [L]
```

And this is the redirect when registration is successfully

```
header('Location:  login/?action=joined/');
exit;
```

**Note**: With normal URL's is working and there is no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable to match it.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(action=joined)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^login/$ /userAction.php?%1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^login/$ /userAction.php [NC,L]
```

The order of rules is also important. Alternatively, you can try the following approach:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^login/$ /userAction.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

Note the `QSA` flag above.